# Show each file's read/write rate

Tags: linux, centos

Is there a command in linux (more specifically on CentOS 5), that shows how many bytes/sec each file is being read in the past few second. A similar tool in win7 is the Resource Monitor, which can show each file's read speed, and it is helpful diagnosing system performance degrade.

It is duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730509/show-each-files-read-write-rate, where I was told to ask here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen pidstat? http://sebastien.godard.pagesperso-orange.fr/man_pidstat.html

`pidstat -d` shows disk io for all processes.

Some horribly hacky bash:

`lsof myfilename | grep -v PID | awk '{print $2}' | xargs pidstat -d -p`

For general system info (which is what use for system performance), I love iostat.

`iostat -x`

Comment: but pidstat still doesn't trace the IO at file level.